# Modernizr vs just providing fallbacks for prefixes within CSS... which one and why

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, modernizr, vendor-prefix

Trying to understand the bigger picture here.  Will use example of css calc.  I have layout that relies heavily upon it, and need some sort of solution for older android, opera, etc.

So... trying to understand which is preferable and why.

Option 1:
Use Modernizr to sniff support then provide fallback if unsupported

Option 2:
Just provide fallback within the css like:
width: 200px;
width: -moz-calc(...)
width: -webkit-calc(...)
width: calc(...)

I think I'm missing some bigger picture of why modernizr is useful as it appears to me in this instance to be a library I could skip and speed up pageload without.  Is it just because there are a number of things I may want to sniff out so it becomes useful due to sheer volume of issues, and it will catch things I might not have been aware of, or is there something else I'm missing?

Really trying ultimately to get viewport unit and calc functionality across all modern-ish browsers (including opera) if that is possible... and trying to see exactly where modernizr would or would not fit into that scenario.

thx

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to use Modernizr, you shouldn't.

Depending on the amount of `calc`s in your code, it may be better to load a [calc polyfill](https://github.com/closingtag/calc-polyfill) (I certainly hope not...calc shouldn't have to be used that much. If it is, something is most likely wrong).

Personally, I wouldn't add Modernizr just to sniff for this one feature. [The actual detect](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/css/calc.js) is very small. I would just implement the logic for it in your own code, basing it off of the detect we use.

So, no, you are not missing anything. It is useful to detect a number of things, but if its just going to be one feature, and that feature isn't terribly complex to detect, there isn't a reason to add it.

Comment: Thx.  That's about what I had gathered, but modernizr is so ubiquitous I thought I might be missing another benefit of that route.  If you don't mind...  I checked out the calc polyfill (among others), but the notes are sparse, and I'm new to js.  Is it finding all instances of "calc" in the stylesheet, doing the computations in js, then passing the value back to the stylesheet?  I think that's what I want, but I'm honestly not sure whether the industry preference to avoid js for layouts, minimize calc is a philosophical/semantic one, or if there are repercussions for the end user.  thx

Comment: Honestly, I am not certain, but that is how I would approach it if I was creating something similar. If you are doing cutting edge or agency work, then pushing boundries with JS polyfills is a-ok. If you are trying to create something longlived and sustainable, better to use pure css. calc is rarely _needed_. It often just makes something a bit simplier